# Horizontal RecylcerView inside RecyclerView vs ViewPager inside RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-pageradapter

I have a recyclerview consists of cards, each card/item has pictures that need to be scrolled horizontally. Which is a better to implement? I have done it with a viewpager but I'm not sure if I should rather go with RecyclerView instead of a viewpager? Any tips?

Comment: can you give your code sample here. I also have to make an exactly same view.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what kind of scroll do you want. `ViewPager` will scroll whole page, where `RecyclerView` will allow you to scroll only part of view.

Comment: Its not an issue, In my viewpager layout I have multiple ImageView, if im going with a recyclerView it will have a single Imageview, and have the RecyclerView layout seted as Gridlayout devided into two coloumns, my main issue is the performance/memory leak

Comment: @busted13 if you properly handle destroying view in `ViewPager`, there won't be leaks. But i'm really will stay with `RecyclerView` in your case. It will inflate more efficiently and so on.